# how can I adjust gnome shell top bar icon alignment on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell

I've just install Ubuntu 20.04.

I added many gnome-shell extensions, but the top bar's icon alignment is weired.

Some icons overlap other icons.

How can I adjust icons' alignment??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/

This extension helps adjust icons' padding.